# How to accurately monitor hair loss?

Tags: hairloss

I've been using Minoxidil for a while, and I just stopped recently. I couldn't see a difference in hair loss while taking a shower. But how can I be more certain about the change in hair loss? Pulling hair to see how strong they are?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as primarily opinion-based because unless there's a widespread medical procedure of monitoring hair loss explained in literature (which - spoiler alert - there isn't) asking for an accurate method etc. solely comes down to opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Have someone take photos of the back of your head periodically. Date the photos.

*(Carey's [comment](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/14891/how-to-accurately-monitor-hair-loss#comment23007_14891) seemed good enough to make it an answer.)*

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Makes sense. I just wrote a comment to Carey.

Comment: It's all yours. Trouble is, I didn't make it an answer because it doesn't meet site requirements.  Your job now is to find a supporting reference and add it.

Comment: @Nic Still waiting for a supporting reference....

Comment: For the benefit of others who may be new here (like myself) here's a link to the meta post where it was decided that we [require references for all answers](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers).

Comment: @CareyGregory I don't think there are any references for this type of question. In essence, it's the question that's primarily opinion-based (unless there's a widespread medical procedure of monitoring hair loss explained in literature), so I wouldn't punish the answerer but close the question instead.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Agreed. (I can't believe the question has 5 upvotes.)